# Backbone js - change model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model:

```
App.Models.Education = Backbone.Model.extend({
  schema: {
    university: {
      type: 'Text',
      validators: ['required'],
      editorAttrs: {placeholder: 'Test placeholder'}
    },
   info: {type: 'Text'},
   desc: {type: 'Text'}
})
```

and extend it:

```
App.Models.HighSchool = App.Models.Education.extend({
   initialize: function () {
      //code to change placeholder
      this.set({education_type: init_parameters.school});
   }
});
```

How to change the placeholder text in "university" field of HighSchool?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend setting up your models that way. You should try to avoid nesting attributes because of the exact same issue you're having. It becomes hard to change one particular field.

Instead, can you do something like:

```
App.Models.Education = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { // backbone keyword to have default model attributes
        type: 'Text',
        validators: ['required'],
        editorAttrs: {placeholder: 'Test placeholder'
    }
});

App.Models.HighSchool = App.Models.Education.extend({
   initialize: function () {
       //code to change placeholder
       this.set('editorAttrs', {placeholder: 'new placeholder'});
       this.set('education_type', init_parameters.school); 
   }
});
```

Comment: dont work(( `this.set('university', {editorAttrs: {placeholder: 'new placeholder'}});` is more closer

Comment: with my change, there won't be an `university` attribute

Comment: nope I cant change Education model...upd: a little bit change it at first post